# Find the mistake in the code — we have to print the sum of elements of the array of any size

Tags: c

The elements of the array have to be taken as input from the user.  Here I am using an array of size 10. I am getting the sum as 0 if I initialized it with `sum = 0;` while declaring, and if I didn't, I am getting a garbage value.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int barray[10], i=0, sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++ ){
        printf("Enter the value for barray[%d] element of the array :  ",i);
        scanf("%d", &barray[i]);
    }
    while(i >=0 && i<10)
    {
        sum += barray[i];
        i++;
    }
    printf("The sum of the elements of the array is %d", sum);
        
}
```

Comment: Not initializing `sum` to zero would clearly be wrong because you want to start adding at `0`. The issue in your code is quite simple: What value is `i` when the `while` loop begins?

Comment: You should use a `for` loop when looping a known number of iterations. In this example, since you know beforehand the number of iterations of the loop (which is `sizeof(barray)/sizeof(*barray)`), then you shouldn't use a `while` loop to iterate over it.

Comment: Since you declared `i` at the start of main (and not in the body of the for loop) it will be set to 10 after the for loop ends, hence the while loop doesn't even start.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that `i` is not a variable declared in the scope of the for loop but in the scope of main, so when the for loop is done `i=10` and then the contents of the while loop are skipped as the condition for `i` to be greater than 0 and less than 10 are never met.

To fix this you should set `i` to zero after the for loop

```
    scanf("%d", &barray[i]);
}
i = 0; // add this
while(i >=0 && i<10)
{
```

or change the while loop to a for loop like the first one. Though I would recommend as good practice and for cleaner code to declare the iterator variable inside the context of the for loop unless you need to access it outside of it, like so.

```
int main(void)
{
    int barray[10], sum=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("Enter the value for barray[%d] element of the array :  ", i);
        scanf("%d", &barray[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        sum += barray[i];
    }
    printf("The sum of the elements of the array is %d", sum);
}
```

Comment: There's no particular reason to store the values in an array; they could be stored one at a time in an ordinary variable, and the sum calculated as the data is read.  That said, the question stipulates "The elements of the array have to be taken as input from the user", in which case maybe the array is necessary to satisfy the teacher, even though the problem doesn't need an array.

Comment: As this is almost certainly a class assignment, it makes sense for them to learn about arrays, and their teacher likely plans to build on this for performing other operations on that set of numbers.